# dbt selected_resources variable is empty

Tags: dbt

In dbt documentation it says this variable `length_selected_resources` is available with the selected resources.
But for me it's coming empty. Why?

E.g.:

Command I run:

```
dbt run --select marts.growth
```

Log inside a macro:

```
{% do log("length_selected_resources_LOG::"~length_selected_resources, info=true) %}
```

Empty variable output:
[image]

> Reference:
> https://docs.getdbt.com/reference/dbt-jinja-functions/selected_resources

[EDIT]
The variable name was invalid.
As Adam pointed out in the comments for length we should use `selected_resources | length`

Comment: Double check the documentation. The variable is `selected_resources`. If you want the length of the array, use `{% do log("length_selected_resources_LOG::"~ (selected_resources | length), info=true) %}`

Comment: Good catch. Thank you Adam. The correct variable worked as expected.